# What is the difference between Dispatcher view and Service to work design pattern?

Tags: design-patterns, jakarta-ee

What is the main difference between Dispatcher view and Service to work design pattern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference is that Service to Worker describes architectures with more behavior "up front" in the controller and dispatcher, while Dispatcher View describes architectures with more behavior moved back to the time of view processing. Thus, the two patterns suggest a continuum, where behavior is either encapsulated closer to the front or moved farther back in the process flow. - ([Sun Blueprints, Dispatcher View Pattern](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/patterns/DispatcherView.html))